# I want to use a There.is.already.a.file.with.the.same.name dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, file

Is there a built-in Dialog in visual studio for this? or do I have to customize a form by myself?

Comment: Why not use a message box?

Comment: save file dialog automatically asks this question if the file exist in where you specified

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Since windows explorer has that dialog I thought I'd use that to create a consistent feel.

Comment: @Arash Ohhh so that's what it's called! Thanks.. I was using file.io to make the copies

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `SaveFileDialog` which has this functionality built in, however if this does not fit into your project you can use a `MessageBox` to display the notification to the user.

If you want user feedback from the dialog and your requirements do not fit into the available MessageBoxButtons options, you could create a custom dialog yourself by creating a form with required label/buttons.

Comment: SaveFileDialog won't work since each file has it's own folder. Neither does MessageBox since it does not let me choose to replace or ignore.

Comment: In which case it sounds like you will have to create a custom dialog yourself to satisfy your requirements, see updated answer.

Comment: Hey my goal is to open up the second form in the catch statement for my main form. I tried to Application.Run(new Popup()); and .ShowDialog but neither are allowed

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific dialogue. The `SaveFileDialog` will already handle this situation. Otherwise just do;

```
 MessageBox.ShowDialog("A file with that name already exists.");
 // showdialogue forces focus to the messagebox until it's dismissed
```